# Why my page have long total blocking time on PageSpeed?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, pagespeed, lighthouse, google-pagespeed

My team and I trying to improve my page performance and I started from testing it from [PageSpeed](https://pagespeed.web.dev/)

We saw that my page have long Total blocking time there (somewhere between 4,500ms - 7,000ms).
We are using React.js for our app and off-course we are using client side rendering.
We are loading the js chunks from our server and we have 1 chunk that his size is 3kb and it's taking us around 4,000ms to loading him specifically.
How is this even possible that it's take so long to download/block the page rendering for 4,000ms for script with size of 3kb?
What is the steps that you can recommend me to do in order to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

> How is this even possible that it's take so long to download/block the page rendering for 4,000ms for script with size of 3kb?

It's possible because even a small amount of code can be slow. The most extreme example of this is `while(true)`. In reality, how much work the code does and the number of times it needs to do it will affect its TBT. Also keep in mind that these values are probably throttled on a simulated slow mobile device.

To the actual question of how to fix slow TBT, you could read more in some of these guides:

- https://web.dev/optimize-long-tasks/
- https://web.dev/client-side-rendering-of-html-and-interactivity/
- https://web.dev/tbt/#how-to-improve-tbt